how to properly initialize an array?
I am trying to understand how arrays work and ran into a problem. I have understood that arrays are a fixed data type and once defined cannot go out of it's bounds. However, the below method seems to be working fine and I don't understand why. Do I have an incomplete understanding of arrays
    private static int[] return_Array()
    {
       int[] arr = new int[5];

       arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

       return arr;
    } 

Even if I did
arr = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}; it's working without any error
Shouldn't I get an Index was outside the bounds of the array error in both scenarios?

In your first statement, you declare a variable (arr) as an array of int and initialize it to a newly created empty array. Then, in your second statement, you assign a new array (this time of 6 ints) to that variable. The original array no longer has any references to it and will be collected. If you had said a[5] = 6: you would have seen the exception you were expecting

No, because you're making a new array, throwing away the first one. You can only ever assign an int array to arr, but nothing stops you making a new longer int array. You need to understand that when you use the word "new" (which the short hand syntax of [...]does under the hood) it isn't writing the 6 elements into the old array of size 5, it's discarding the 5 and replacing it entirely with a new 6

Okay I assumed as much but the whole thing was confusing. Thank you for your answers.

@MohammedImadh Do not tag this question as dsa.  Please read what the tags are for before applying them.  The dsa tag is for Digital Signature Algorithm.

You are not adding values to the array, you are replacing it.
int[] arr = new int[5]; --> int[] arr = [0,0,0,0,0]
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];    --> int[] arr = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6} 


What I am doing here essentially is discarding the first statement where I declare an array of size 5 and creating an entirely new array of size 6.
Because an array is a reference type the second statement is overriding the first with new keyword (where '[]' is the shorthand of it).

this has nothing to do with an array being a reference-type. The same of course happens, when you reassign an int:  int i = 4; i = 3 will also replace the existing integer. The =-operator will assing the value on the right side to the variable on the left. So whatever was in that variable in the first place, will allways be replaced by the new value.

@MakePeaceGreatAgain But isn't that a behavior of a reference type?
